# How to Export and Require Modules in Node js

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I want to setup MVC pattern with Nodejs , Express and Georedis, I've included all required modules in single file under `config/require_module.js` as -

```
var all_modules = {};
all_modules.express  = require('express');
all_modules.router   = all_modules.express.Router();
all_modules.redis    = require('redis');
all_modules.client   = all_modules.redis.createClient();
all_modules.georedis = require('georedis');
all_modules.fs       = require('fs');
all_modules.mysqlPool = require('./myqlConn');
all_modules.locationsController = require('./../controllers/locations');

module.exports = all_modules;
```

And in `controller/locations.js` I included this file as -

```
`var  allModules = require('./../config/require_module');`
```

I called georedis module like -

```
exports.update_location = function(req, res) {

    var geo = allModules.georedis.initialize(allModules.client, {
        zset: 'LocationsSet',
        nativeGeo: false
    });
};
```

but it is throwing an exception -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at exports.update_location (/var/www/html/nodeRedisRestexample/controllers/locations.js:27:34)
```

locations.js line 27 is

```
var geo = allModules.georedis.initialize(allModules.client, {
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of tools for scaffolding a node application, why don't you use one of them? Why don't you follow conventions and use tools like `npm`, create `package.json`? When creating a node application usually the main file is called `server.js`, `app.js`, `index.js`. You're inventing some basic things new. Also when you require `express`, you have to execute it as function in order to generate the application object: `var express = require('express'); var app = express();`. Now you can use the variable `app` to execute the methods provided by `express`.

Comment: I would get rid of require_module.js file and just load modules whenever needed in each controller. if you worry about loading a module twice node already have mechanism to prevent that.

Comment: @cezar , thank you for reply , but I just wanted to know why it is not possible? same code is working in routes.js file but not in controller.

Comment: @AmirHoseinian , yes when I explicitly include modules in controller then it is working. Is it not possible to include all required modules in a single file and include that file whenever needed ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but I know that it isn't the right way. it will just lead to loading all the modules on every request when you just need a handful of them